# Jsoup - multiple css styles inside one class & element count

Tags: jsoup

```
 <div class="opomnikRight">
                <div>
                    <p class="contentTitle">Institucija</p>
                    <a href="/drzava-in-druzba/javni-sektor/podrobnosti-institucije.html?id=2322">UPRAVNA ENOTA RADOVLJICA</a>
                </div>
                <div class="marginTop20">
                    <p class="contentTitle">Št. zadeve</p>
                    <p>330 - 63 / 2016</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spacer10">
                    <p class="contentTitle">Št. dokumenta</p>
                    <p>330 - 63 / 2016 - 6</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="contentTitle">Datum in število dni objave</p>
                        <p>29. 1. 2016 (objava do 28. 2. 2016)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

code:

```
String html = upper html;
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
divs = doc.getElementsByClass("opomnikRight");
```

1. `divs.get(0).getElementsByTag("div").size();`
   gives me 5 !?
2. divs = doc.getElementsByClass("opomnikRight")`;
   divs = doc.getElementsByClass("opomnikRight foo")`;

   second line does not work , how to handle such cases. As far as I know that is legal:
   class = "opomnikRight foo", and it also has effect in html

Answer (score 1):

**About 1:**

According to the [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag-java.lang.String-), the `getElementsByTag` method selects all tags matching the given name, including the top level, so you get the outer div plus all included divs:

> `public Elements getElementsByTag(String tagName)`
>
> Finds elements,
>   including and recursively under this element, with the specified tag
>   name.

**About 2:**

Selecting multiple classes can be done using the CSS slector syntax. Here a class is defined by its name and a preceding dot. So you would find the elements like this:

```
Elements divs = doc.select(".opomnikRight.foo");
```